# Timed particle emitters in Phaser 3

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I'm adding a blood effect for when enemies are hit in my game and I want to be able to specify how long the particle emitter will emit particles for, but the lifespan property when creating a particle emitter is the lifespan of the particles, not the emitter. Is there something like this, or another way? I could set it to off after a minute but I'm not sure how a ton of inactive particle emitters would affect performance.

```
this.add.particles({
//particle stuff
emitterLifespan: 1000
})
```

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tldr;** *("easy" solution simply  use `setTimeout(() => emiter.stop(), 1000)` , to stop the emitter. In the demo below, it is the last/yellow  emitter)*

I don't know of any such property, and is also not mentioned in [the documentation](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Types.GameObjects.Particles.html#.ParticleEmitterConfig) (or the unofficial [more hands on documentation](https://rexrainbow.github.io/phaser3-rex-notes/docs/site/particles/))

I had the same problem, since the particles work abit odd, I think.
It seems you must balance the properies carefully. For the basic scenario, (seen below), the following properties could cause a problem:

- `lifespan`  *lifespan of emitted particles*
- `maxParticles` *hard limit of particles*
- `frequency` *milliseconds for emit cycle*

I noticed if the particles "die" before it reaches `maxParticles`, the emitter won't "stop".

You could configer the properties, so that the emitter stop when it reaches the max ( the **red** particles in the example), or you could use the `setTimeout` function to stop it, after some time(like the **yellow** particles). **Green** and **blue** just show how different values won't stop the emitter. *(due to the random part, and depending on the performance of the browser/pc, this might run forever or stop. On my CellPhone the **blue** emitter stops, but the **green** ones don't. And on my PC **green** and **blue** run for "ever")*

```js
document.body.style = 'margin:0;';

var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 536,
    height: 183,
    physics: {
        default: 'arcade',
        arcade: {            
            gravity:{ y: 100 },
            debug: true
        }
    },
    scene: {
        create
    },
    banner: false
}; 

function create () {

    this.add.text(10,10, 'Click to Create Blood').setOrigin(0);
    let g = this.make.graphics({add:false});
    
    g.fillStyle(0xffffff)
    g.fillCircle(4,4,4);
    g.generateTexture('blood', 8, 8)
    
    let particles = this.add.particles('blood');

    this.input.on('pointerdown',  p => {
        particles.createEmitter({
            tint: 0xff0000,
            alpha: { start: 1, end: 0 },
            scale: { start: 0.5, end: 1.5 },
            speed: {random: [20, 100] },
            accelerationY:  {random: [-100, 200] },
            rotate: { min: -180, max: 180 },
            lifespan: { min: 300, max: 800 },
            frequency: 20,
            maxParticles: 10,
            x: p.x,
            y: p.y
        });    

        particles.createEmitter({
            alpha: { start: 1, end: 0 },
            tint: 0x00ff00,
            scale: { start: 0.5, end: 1.5 },
            speed: {random: [20, 100] },
            accelerationY:  {random: [-100, 200] },
            rotate: { min: -180, max: 180 },
            lifespan: { min: 300, max: 800 },
            frequency: 120,
            maxParticles: 10,
            x: p.x + 100,
            y: p.y
        });    
        
        particles.createEmitter({
            alpha: { start: 1, end: 0 },
            tint: 0x0000ff,
            scale: { start: 0.5, end: 1.5 },
            speed: {random: [20, 100] },
            accelerationY:  {random: [-100, 200] },
            rotate: { min: -180, max: 180 },
            lifespan: { min: 200, max: 300 },
            frequency: 10,
            maxParticles: 20,
            x: p.x + 200,
            y: p.y
        });    
        
          let emitter = particles.createEmitter({
            alpha: { start: 1, end: 0 },
            tint: 0xffff00,
            scale: { start: 0.5, end: 1.5 },
            speed: {random: [20, 100] },
            accelerationY:  {random: [-100, 200] },
            rotate: { min: -180, max: 180 },
            lifespan: { min: 200, max: 300 },
            frequency: 10,
            maxParticles: 20,
            x: p.x + 300,
            y: p.y
        }); 
        
        // Stop after 1000 ms
        setTimeout(()=> emitter.stop(), 1000);
    });

}

new Phaser.Game(config);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.55.2/dist/phaser.js"></script>
```

> **btw.:** you could also use the `explode` function if all particles should be *emitted* at once, checkout this [official example](https://phaser.io/examples/v3/view/game-objects/particle-emitter/explode-test), and here the [link to the documenation](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.GameObjects.Particles.ParticleEmitter.html#explode__anchor).